# Что такое франшиза?

Tags: неологизмы

Из газет: "В центре зеленой зоны появится тот самый "диснейленд" под франшизой Dreamworks (название кинокомпании)".

Что такое франшиза, каким синонимом ее можно заменить? Говорят, что "когда в России отсутствовали рыночные экономические отношения, в языке, естественно, не существовало в обиходе и таких слов, как франшиза, брокер, толлинг, и многих других".

Вы знаете, что такое франшиза? ― Это что-то вроде…   **А сколько значений у этого слова, можно ли его применять вне экономических тем, в переносном смысле? А вы используете его в своей речи?**

Пример

Я попросил его показать мне контракт, прежде чем посылать заявку на оплату страховки. Оказалось, что франшиза 900 долларов. Мой друг (а он врач) был поражен: что такое «франшиза» он в точности не знал, но ассоциировалось это у него с чем-то приятным ― с галлами, с Парижем…

Comment: Если вы хотите создать метку из более чем одного слова, используйте дефис.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Франшиза - нематериальная собственность (чаще всего - бренд), передаваемая по договору для использования.

> > Франши́за (фр. franchise — льгота) может означать следующее:
> >
> > Франшиза — объект договора франчайзинга, комплекс благ, состоящий из   прав пользования брендом и бизнес-моделью франчайзера, а также иных благ,   необходимых для создания и ведения бизнеса. В качестве франшизы могут   выступать методы ведения бизнеса, товарный знак, технология со взаимными   обязательствами и льготами между передающей (франчайзер) и получающей   (франчайзи) сторонами, предоставляемые за плату и оформленные
> >     в соответствии с законом об охране интеллектуальной собственности.

(Вики).

Там еще несколько значений есть, но они в русском языке не столь значимы.

Comment: Как будет звучать исходное предложение без слова "франшиза"? И какой смысл экономических отношений (речь идет о строительстве детского парка в Нагатинском затоне)? Компания платит городу за рекламу ее персонажей в парке?

Comment: Без слова "франшиза" предать точное значение очень сложно. Но в разговоре можно сказать "под *вывеской* Дримворк". Город тут вообще ни при чем. Франшиза (*объект*) - название  "Дримворк", которое кинокомпания передала парку (московскому, судя по всему, ибо по тексту - вряд ли тут замешано само детище Диснея, хотя шут его знает, журналюги могли и напутать).

Answer (score 0):

Подробнее о том, что такое франшиза, и некоторые аспекты [тут](http://nicefinance.ru/2019/07/09/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%8F/).